# Are enchantment probabilities different depending on the tool?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, I am trying to get a toolsmith villager to offer a diamond pickaxe enchanted with Unbreaking 3, Fortune 2 and Efficiency 3.
I tried resetting its trades at least a hundred times and I have been unsuccessful since I have gotten the same enchants on a shovel multiple times. Are the probabilities of getting the same enchantments on a pickaxe different/non existent or am I just extremely unlucky?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "hundred attempts"? What are you trying to do with the villager?

Comment: @pinckerman I've been resetting its trades.

Comment: How does one reset villager trades? Breaking the workstation only works if you haven't traded with the villager yet, but they won't offer diamond tools until they level up by trading a few times. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-enchant-1.8-2) for both the Bedrock and Java Editions and all tools:

> When creating an enchantment offer, the game uses a random enchantment
> level from 5 – 19. The enchantments are never treasure enchantments.

So there should be no difference in the probability of getting a certain enchantment for different tools.

Comment: I believe the quality of the tool does have an effect on this? Eg. Wood, vs diamond, vs gold?

Comment: @Ben That is true when using an enchantment table, op is asking for villager trading. That does not apply here.

Comment: ah yes true! I missed that part :)